# Send associative array from HTML to JS

Tags: php, html, arrays, twig, custom-data-attribute

I need to send few values through html data attribute to JS.

```
 <div class="article"
       data-article="[{% for data in article %}{{ data }},{% endfor %}]"
>
```

I use foreach to get each element of **existing associative** array to create new one which is in data attribute.

This works well but I want to send whole array in this case article if there is some way for that

I know that array can be send via data HTML attribute but I wonder if I can send associative array in reason to avoid multi data attributes in one html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JSON in this case

when you build the html with php use

```
    data-article=JSON_encode($yourarray)
```

Now the html will have the array.  you can decode it in JS with

```
   JSON.parse($("div.article")[0].dataset.article)
```

Comment: To be most correct, this is not a TWIG solution. However it is totally doable with TWIG as well: `data-article="{{ article|json_encode|raw }}"`

Answer (score 0):

I was made solution from the accoundant sugestion.

JSON is helping me, but I again must do it in foreach when symfony twig is rendering array

I do that on this way

```
data-article='[{ {% for key,value in article %}{% if i > 0 %},{% endif %}"{{ key}}":"{{ value }}"{% set i = i+1 %}{% endfor %} }]'>
```

**IT MUST BE IN ONE ROW**

```
{% set i = 0 %}
data-article='
 [{ 
    {% for key,value in article %}
        {% if i > 0 %},{% endif %}
        "{{ key}}":"{{ value }}"
        {% set i = i+1 %}{% endfor %} 
 }]
'>
```